# Is there a way to get the constraints of a table in SQLite?

Tags: database, list, sqlite, constraints, pragma

The command `pragma table_info('tablename')` lists the columns information and `pragma foreign_key_list('tablename')` the foreign keys.
How can I display other constraints (check, unique) of a table?
Only parsing the field "sql" of the table "sqlite_master"?

Comment: There's also "pragma index_list('tablename')" See http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_list

Comment: @Nabab you should really consider adding that as an answer

Answer (score 16):

I think the only way is to do this is the way you suggested, parse the sql column of the sqlite_master database.

Python code to do this:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("example.sqlite3")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select sql from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='example_table'")
schema = cur.fetchone()
con.close()

entries = [ tmp.strip() for tmp in schema[0].splitlines() if tmp.find("constraint")>=0 or tmp.find("unique")>=0 ]
for i in entries: print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's also `pragma index_list('tablename')`

See http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_list

Comment: Not all indexes are constraints, and not all constraints are indexes.

Answer (score 3):

In **SQLite**, this command below shows the details of a table **including Table Constraints**:

```
.schema table_name
```

And this command below shows the details of tables **excluding Table Constraints**:

```
PRAGMA table_info(table_name);
```